# How to read pdf contains in .tar file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, apache-tika

I have files in .tar file, I am able to extract the members from the ##.tar file, and I am also using tika parser to parse the pdf files, received file not found error.

```
 with tarfile.open(os.path.join(DEFAULT_PATH,filename), "r") as tarf:
    for members in tarf.getmembers():
        f = tarf.extractfile(members)
        parsed_pdf =  parser.from_file(f)
```

and I dont want to extract the pdf in another directory and just read from .tar file

Answer (score 0):

Able to resolve above by using below code

```
        for members in tarf.getnames()[1:]:

           tarf.extract( members, './full_text')
           parsed_pdf =  parser.from_file(os.path.join(DEFAULT_PATH,filename))
```